# Ler idade em dias e expressar em anos, meses e dias - Exercício

Tags: java

Alguém sabe me dizer como fazer o inverso desse programa? Tipo em vez de ler a idade de uma pessoa em anos, meses e dias e expressar apenas em dias, Ler em dias e expressar em anos, meses e dias ?
`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int IdadeAnos , IdadeMeses, IdadeDias, IdadeTotalDias;
    
    System.out.print("Calculadora de idade em dias\n\n"); 


    System.out.print("Digite os anos: ");
    IdadeAnos = entrada.nextInt();
    
    System.out.print("Digite os meses: ");
    IdadeMeses = entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Digite os dias: ");
    IdadeDias = entrada.nextInt();


    IdadeTotalDias = IdadeAnos * 365 + IdadeMeses * 30 + IdadeDias;
    System.out.print("Idade total em dias = "+IdadeTotalDias+"\n");
    
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Seu professor provavelmente ficaria decepcionado se te déssemos a resposta de mão beijada -- e este sequer é o objetivo do SO. Mas o caminho das pedras é o seguinte: você divide pelos dias do ano e descobre a quantidade de anos; o resto da divisão você divide pelos dias do mês, e assim por diante.

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dias;
    int anos = 0;
    int meses = 0;

    System.out.print("Calculadora de idade em anos, meses e dias!\n\n"); 


    System.out.print("Digite os dias: ");
    dias = entrada.nextInt();

    while (dias >= 365) {
        dias = dias - 365;
        anos += 1;
        if (dias < 365) {
            while (dias >= 30) {
                dias = dias - 30;
                meses += 1;
            }
        }
    }



    System.out.printf("Anos: %d\nMeses: %d\nDias: %d\n", anos, meses, dias);

}
```